# css file not being found by thymeleaf

Tags: servlets, thymeleaf

I try to do simple servlet that generates pdf file based on HTML template. I try to use Thymeleaf and FlyingSaucer, as in [example](https://tuhrig.de/generating-pdfs-with-java-flying-saucer-and-thymeleaf)

in my template.hmtl i have style delcaration as follow:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css"/>
```

it never gets loaded. No error, nothing, just resulting .pdf is missing style. If I put content of style file into template.HTML it works like charm.

If I put something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://localhost:8080/MY_APP/resources/style.css"/>
```

it works.

All my resources are under `src/main/webapp/resources`.

Comment: Have you tried with Thymeleaf's [URL syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls)? (`th:href="@{...}"` instead of plain `href`)

Comment: @JakubCh. no luck

Comment: I want to point out, that I am not trying to display this template as web page - I am trying to make pdf file based on that template and serve it to user thru servlet.

Comment: I have no time to reproduce... But you should check out comments section in enclosed example. Those two from April 10th and April 25th, 2018 seem to tackle a problem you're struggling with.

Comment: hey!
Already did. Nothing really helpful. I've found solution thou.

Answer (score 0):

After few more hours of researching problem, this is what I've end up with.

For CSS - only solution that I've found was to just put CSS in HTML templates. Not elegant, but does the job (at least for now). Not a big issue, as I use those templates to generate pdf files.

But the same issue was with image files, but that one I was able to solve in elegant way. Here is it!

Problem was that in web container Java couldn't find files pointed in .html templates.
So I had to write custom Element Factory extending ReplacedElementFactory. here is code for that:

```
public class B64ImgReplacedElementFactory implements ReplacedElementFactory {

    public ReplacedElement createReplacedElement(LayoutContext c, BlockBox box, UserAgentCallback uac, int cssWidth, int cssHeight) {
        Element e = box.getElement();
        if (e == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String nodeName = e.getNodeName();
        if (nodeName.equals("img")) {
            String attribute = e.getAttribute("src");
            FSImage fsImage;
            try {
                fsImage = buildImage(attribute);
            } catch (BadElementException e1) {
                fsImage = null;
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                fsImage = null;
            }
            if (fsImage != null) {
                if (cssWidth != -1 || cssHeight != -1) {
                    fsImage.scale(cssWidth, cssHeight);
                }
                return new ITextImageElement(fsImage);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected FSImage buildImage(String srcAttr) throws IOException, BadElementException {

            URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(srcAttr);
            if (res != null) {
                return new ITextFSImage(Image.getInstance(res));
            } else {
                return null;
        }
    }

    public void remove(Element e) {
    }

    public void reset() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setFormSubmissionListener(FormSubmissionListener listener) {
    }
}
```

and use case in code generating PDF file:

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
SharedContext sharedContext = renderer.getSharedContext();
sharedContext.setReplacedElementFactory(new B64ImgReplacedElementFactory());
```

custom element replaces catches all occurrence of 'img' nodes, and uses ClasLoader to get resource path, and based on that FSImage is returned, and that is what we need.

Hope that helps!